# Make grep to exact match strings with and without dash "-"

Tags: linux, awk, grep

The problem looks simple and common, so I've looked through many answers but seems that none of them provides appropriate general solution.
I need to `grep` large tab-separated 6 columns file (*.bed file in fact) to split it by the content of the first column using the list of string variables (items). I just need a row starting with a given string.

I was succesfully using

```
grep -w "$name" inputfile
```

`$name` is read from the list of strings 
for that purpose until the case where strings have the following format (example): **YAL038W** but also **YAL038W-A**, **YAL038W-B**,... 
So, `grep` with `-w` option considers **YAL038W** identical to **YAL038W-A**, **YAL038W-B** since "`-`" is word separator. it would work with "`_`" but not with "`-`".

I've found solutions based on `awk` which are working fine, for example:

```
awk -F $'\t' -vsearch=$name '$1==search' inputfile
```

but `awk` is terribly slow, over 10 times, see time measurements below
For 2.5 Gb input file and > 5000 items to look for, script is already running for >24 hours!

Example of inputfile:

```
YAL038W-A       0       48      HWI-1KL176:101:CC27NACXX:3:2208:17646:92047     0       +
YAL038W-A       0       48      HWI-1KL176:101:CC27NACXX:3:2211:17326:31268     0       +
YAL038W 1       50      HWI-1KL176:101:CC27NACXX:8:1205:16311:19319     3       +
YAL038W 1       27      HWI-1KL176:101:CC27NACXX:8:2103:4951:94527      42      +
```

```
time grep -w "YAL038W" inputfile > testfile.txt
real    0m3.569s

time awk -F $'\t' -vsearch="YAL038W" '$1==search' inputfile > testfile.txt
real    0m29.521s
```

I am looking for FAST solution using `grep` or something else, and I need to pass the variable to this command in the cycle.
Alternative is to modify the imput file by replacing "`-`" by "`_`", but it is the last possibility I believe...
Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to want `grep -E "(^|[[:space:]])$name(\$|[[:space:]])" inputfile` or, if the value must appear at the start of a line, ``grep -E "^$name(\$|[[:space:]])" inputfile``

Comment: When you say `$name is read from the list of strings for that purpose` - would I be right in thinking you have your grep or awk command wrapped in a loop that's reading each name one at a time from some other file? If so then that's a far bigger performance concern than which tool you use for the search. Show THAT code if you want help improving the performance of your script.

Comment: Dear Ed Morton,  Thanks for this suggestion, indeed, my code is probably not optimal: I am using the following loop structure: while read -r RNA
do  awk -F $'\t' -vsearch="$RNA_name" '$1==search' mapped_RNA.bed > mapped_RNA_$RNA_name.bed  ..... done < RNA_list.csv   There is another grep with the same $RNA_name in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've found solutions based on `awk` which are working fine, for example:
>
> ```
> awk -F $'\t' -vsearch=$name '$1==search' inputfile
> ```
>
> but `awk` is terribly slow…
>
> I am looking for FAST solution using `grep` …

If the above `awk` command worked for you, then this will do:

```
grep ^$name$'\t' inputfile
```

Just search at the beginning of each line for the name followed by a TAB.

Comment: Yes, 
     grep ^$name$'\t' inputfile    works fine in my case. Thanks a lot